# SQL Server 2005 installs Visual Studio 2005 too?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, installation

I just installed SQL Server 2005 and it installed Visual Studio 2005 too. What's the point of this? Is there an option in the SQL Server installation that can prevent this. If I uninstall Visual Studio now will it mess anything up? What if I now install Visual Studio 2008 too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The visual studio that you get is a shell called Business Intelligence Development studio and it allows you to create Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects. Also it allows you to deploy those projects to your SQL Server. If you already have Visual Studio installed, it will add those project types to it.

With the Development Studio you can add .Net projects such as C# or VB to your Analysis Services or Reporting Services projects to create custom components for them. There are additional benefits, but you should just do a search for Business Intelligence Development Studio to see what else can be done.

EDIT:

I just noticed that you were asking about what happens if you uninstall Visual Studio 2008. There should be a listing under your installed Programs called Visual Studio Shell or something of that nature, which is the Business Intelligence Development Studio and is independent of the main Visual Studio 2008 install. Both of them will allow you to create the Ms SQl Projects that I listed above. When you uninstall Visual Studio 2008 it won't uninstall this application and vice verse. If you do accidentally delete it, you can always install it again using your MS SQL CDs. There are instructions on the web to do so.

Comment: i was a little skeptical that uninstalling VS from Add/Remove Programs would completely uninstall all the BI pieces, so I tried running the SQL server installation again and just not including the BI component. But the installer didn't recognize that as being any different from the current instance, so it wouldn't proceed. I ended up scrapping the whole thing and just reinstalling SQL from a clean OS. thank goodness for VMs :)

Answer (score 0):

The version of Visual Studio that  gets installed is necessary for doing the work you need to do in SQL Server.  The old tools are going away, and this is part of the new.

Personally, I miss the Enterprise manager and SQL Query Analyzer from the SQL Server 2000 days, but they aren't likely to come back.

***Edit - added***

OK. The above was a bit flippant for an answer.

But to answer your comment, Management Studio ***IS*** Visual Studio, configured and modified to work with SQL Server.

Comment: what does visual studio do that management studio doesn't? does seem necessary to me to have VS in a production environment

Comment: You seriously like Enterprise Manager 2000 better?  Holy smokes those things sucked compared to Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, but they were clean and easy to work with.  I'm just strange enough that I think that Windows 2000 Professional was the best version of Windows ever.  All of the newer versions are too cartoony for me, and work too hard at being "friendly", so the more utilitarian Enterprise manager is more my style.

Comment: The 2000 Enterprise Manager didn't even allow me to have multiple stored procs open at 1 time!